# How to convert application written in asp.net 3.5 to 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

How to convert an application written in asp.net 3.5 to 2.0? I have a system in which there is only .net 2.0 . But my application is written in 3.5. I published that app using an another system (3.5 framework) and then I copy that published folder to my system (2.0 framework)and configured in IIS.When i try to browse,i got version problem error.

Comment: Why you need to convert in 2 ?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228009.aspx

Comment: Can you expand more on why this is required? .NET 3.5 is essentially .NET 2.0 with some extra DLLs, but you host it in any .NET 2.0 App Pool on IIS, for instance. Why is upgrading to 3.5 out of the question? And do you know what .NET 3.5-specific functionality is used by the application?

Comment: "@callisto...Thank you for your detailed reply " - my pleasure.
If it is the answer you want, upvote and mark it as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3.5 is 2.0 with a few extra libraries. So you can run them on the same web site. In fact you cannot even set a web application to run under 3.5. It just runs under 2.0.

ASP.NET 3.5 is still running on the .NET 2.0 CLR, if you go into IIS you'll see that you can only pick 2.0 or 1.1
So, if you REALLY want to go back to 2.0, replace all 3.5 stuff with 2.0 stuff: see the lists below.

The new stuff after 2.0 up to 3.5 is:

NET framework 3.0:

Includes a new set of managed code APIs that are an integral part of Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 operating systems and provides

- Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), formerly called Indigo; a service-oriented messaging system which allows programs to interoperate locally or remotely similar to web services.
- Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), formerly called Avalon; a new user interface subsystem and API based on XML and vector graphics, which uses 3D computer graphics hardware and Direct3D technologies.
- Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) allows for building of task automation and integrated transactions using workflows.
- Windows CardSpace, formerly called InfoCard; a software component which securely stores a person's digital identities and provides a unified interface for choosing the identity for a particular transaction, such as logging in to a website

.NET framework 3.5:

It implement Linq evolution in language. So we have the folowing evolution in class:

- Linq for SQL, XML, Dataset, Object
- Addin system
- p2p base class
- Active directory
- ASP.NET Ajax
- Anonymous types with static type inference
- Paging support for ADO.NET
- ADO.NET synchronization API to synchronize local caches and server side datastores
- Asynchronous network I/O API
- Support for HTTP pipelining and syndication feeds.
- New System.CodeDom namespace.

If your application uses any of the above, you'd need to strip it out and replace with something not on the lists.

Comment: @callisto...Thank you for your detailed reply